# Helvetica Neue Font Issue in firefox

Tags: html, css, windows, firefox

I install Helvetica Neue font in my system. in that time Firefox browser Font issue occur. when it use Helvetica Neue font it show double. I attached the issue screen. If any solution available? [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need Remove Helvetica Neue Font family from your system. it over right other Helvetica font form server